# Flutter: Null safety features are disabled for this library when using InterstitialAd? _interstitialAd;

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, google-ads-api

I'm integrating Interstitial ads in my flutter project.
But When I declare like this

```
 InterstitialAd? _interstitialAd;
```

I am getting this error:

```
33:17: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.12 or higher.
  InterstitialAd? _interstitialAd;
                ^
lib/admob_service.dart:64:20: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.12 or higher.
    _interstitialAd!.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
                   ^
lib/admob_service.dart:79:20: Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.12 or higher.
    _interstitialAd!.show();
```

I saw some stackoverflow answers and tried to upgrade the sdk version from

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

to

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

Then I got errors in my whole project.The error message is :

```
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

 - package:local_database
 - package:auto_size_text
 - package:queue
```

Is there any way other than declaring this : InterstitialAd? _interstitialAd;

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the packages you mentioned, haven't been migrated to null safety hence the error.

The only workaround here is you update the packages to their null-safety version (if any) OR just don't use sound null safety for your project.